# Inactive operator in NDSolve (FEM) produces different solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, hold

I am solving a nonlinear PDE in the plane using finite elements iteratively; it is the Laplace--Young equation, $$\nabla \cdot (K(\nabla u) \nabla u) = u, \quad \Omega \\ K(\nabla u) \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = \cos\gamma, \quad \partial\Omega$$

where $K(\mathbf{v}) = 1/\sqrt{1+\mathbf{v}^2}$. To do this I initialise with zero gradient (i.e. $K(\nabla u) = K(\mathbf{0}) = 1$, which leaves $\nabla^2 u = u$, $\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = \cos\gamma$) and solve for $u_0$. Then at step $n$ I replace $K(\nabla u)$ by $k_\text{c} = K(\nabla u_{n-1})$ and solve to obtain $u_n$.

I was playing around with `Inactive` opeartors and ran into trouble at the iterative step where it produced different results to the non-`Inactive` version. To keep things short I am only including a single iterative step rather than the full loop.

```
(* Constants *)
w = 1;
l = 10;
gamma = 1 Degree;
(* Inactive operators *)
div = Inactive[Div][#, {x, y}] &;
grad = Inactive[Grad][#, {x, y}] &;
lap = Inactive[Laplacian][#, {x, y}] &;
(* Domain *)
bound = {x, y, l - x, w - y};
reg = Thread[bound >= 0];
reg = ImplicitRegion[And @@ reg, {x, y}];
(* Boundary *)
dreg = Thread[bound == 0];
(* Finite element mesh *)
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
(* Solver *)
sol[lhs_] :=
 NDSolveValue[
  {lhs == u[x, y]
     (* Only apply flux condition to x == 0 wall *)
     + NeumannValue[-Cos[gamma], dreg[[1]]]
     + NeumannValue[0, dreg[[2]]]
     + NeumannValue[0, dreg[[3]]]
     + NeumannValue[0, dreg[[4]]]
   }, u, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]
```

First I demonstrate how I can produce the same result between non-`Inactive` and `Inactive` at the initialisation step:

```
u0   = sol[Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]]; (* non-Inactive version *)
u0in = sol[lap@u[x, y]];                (* Inactive version *)
(* Plot discrepancy *)
Plot3D[u0[x, y] - u0in[x, y], {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, w}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: u0 no discrepancy]

There is no difference between `u0` and `u0in`. Next I compute $k_\text{c} = K(\nabla u_0)$:

```
kfun = Function[{v}, 1/Sqrt[1 + v.v]];
kc = kfun@Grad[u0[x, y], {x, y}];
```

When I then solve for $u_1$,

```
u1   = sol[Div[kc*Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]]; (* non-Inactive version *) // AbsoluteTiming
u1in = sol[div[kc*grad@u[x, y]]];                  (* Inactive version *)     // AbsoluteTiming
(* Plot discrepancy *)
Plot3D[u1[x, y] - u1in[x, y], {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, w}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Small]
(* {1.02777, Null} *)
(* {0.254934, Null} *)
```

[image: u1 discrepancy]

I get different solutions between `u1` and `u1in` (`Inactive`). Also note that the `Inactive` version only takes a quarter of the time.

Why is there a discrepancy between non-`Inactive` and `Inactive` when solving for $u_1$ (but not when solving for $u_0$)?

Comment: Have a look at how the PDE coefficients get parsed, like shown in the [The Coefficient Form of a PDE](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) section. Careful though the derivative of an `InterpolatingFunction` is still an interpolating function - not sure if this is an issue, just a heads up.

Comment: Voted to close own question (simple mistake found in [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html)); user21 is correct, and the discrepancy is precisely the point of having `Inactive` forms.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. You could delete your question if you have it solved. That does not requite other people to close vote it. Just a thought.

Comment: @lastresort You could also consider writing a self-answer to explain what the problem was for future reference.